# MVC5 Frontend authentication through WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I am developing a web application using MVC5 and WebApi2, but in seperate solutions. I have created a WebApi using ASP.NET Identity, JWT using BearerTokens and user login/creation etc is working beautifully through Postman.

I do have some problems connecting to the web api through MVC though.

The thought is that the Web Api will be deployed to Server A, and the MVC Frontend will be deployed to Server B.

I therefore need to know how to contact and retrieve information from a Web Api through MVC.

I am hoping some of you clever minds have some links to some resources or have a simple answer to the connection part of it all. I would very much prefer using C# and not JS to retrieve the data. (Although if JS is the only way, then i guess i'm learning JS)

Comment: Whats the problem actually? Its CORS problem?

Comment: The problem is i don't know how to even tell MVC to get information from a Web API on a remote server. Which i guess would quality as CORS?

Comment: You´ll work the same way you would do in a javascript app, using requests. Post, get, put... Thats the way you communicate with Web API.
Restsharp [link](http://restsharp.org/) its a REST client for c# that can make this work easier

Comment: I've looked at RestSharp and it helps to some extent, though i can't seem to google my way to an example, where an MVC application, authenticates through a Web Api (On a seperate server), would you happen to know some resources? And thanks for you help so far! :-)

Comment: You will need to authenticate through some kind of token. JWT, Auth0, anything like this. You send the login request with credentials, then if its valid, the webapi should return a token. You store this token and send with subsequent requests in the header. Research for jwt or auth0.

Comment: Alright, ill look into those  technologies. Thank you very much for your help! :-)